# modify column names after filtering source data

Tags: powershell

I would like to modify the column name ResultName if one of the conditions are met

```
$file = gci "q:\test\2018\03\27\sample.*"
$fileData = Import-Csv $file.FullName | Group-Object ResultName | Foreach-Object 
{
    $Ten = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.TypeIndicator -eq '10' }
    $ND =  $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.TypeIndicator -eq 'ND' }

    # Case 1: If Indicator is null or ! for /10 and Indicator is null or ! for ND  
    #         Select line ND and create new row with ResultName + estimated Eg."Al estimated" with ResultEntry = ''
    if(('!','' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('!','' -contains $ND.Indicator)) 
    {
        $ND

        #Case 2: If Indicator is null/! for 10 and Indicator is not null for ND. 
        # Select line ND and create new row with ResultName + estimated Eg."Al estimated" with ResultEntry = ''
    } 
    elseif (('!','' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('o','u' -contains $ND.Indicator)) 
    {
        $Ten
    }

    #Case 3: If Indicator contains either 'o' or 'u' for 10 and Indicateur is null/! for ND 
    # select line ND and create a new row with ResultEntry = ''
    elseif (('o','u' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('!','' -contains $ND.Indicator)) 
    {
        $newValue = $ND | Select-Object -Property @{Name='SampleNumber';Expression={$ND.SampleNumber}},
                                               @{Name='TypeIndicator';Expression={$ND.TypeIndicator}},
                                               @{Name='ResultName';Expression={$ND.ResultName + ' estimed'}},
                                               @{Name='ResultEntry';Expression={$ND.ResultEntry}},
                                               @{Name='Indicator';Expression={$ND.Indicator}}  

    }

    #Case 4: If both /10 and ND contains either o or u, Select line /10
    # select line 10 and create a new row with ResultEntry = ''
    elseif (('u','o' -contains $Ten.Indicator) -and ('o','u' -contains $ND.Indicator)) 
    {
        $newValue = $Ten | Select-Object -Property @{Name='SampleNumber';Expression={$Ten.SampleNumber}},
                                               @{Name='TypeIndicator';Expression={$Ten.TypeIndicator}},
                                               @{Name='ResultName';Expression={$Ten.ResultName + ' estimed'}},
                                               @{Name='ResultEntry';Expression={$Ten.ResultEntry}},
                                               @{Name='Indicator';Expression={$Ten.Indicator}} 
    }
    $newValue  
}
$fileData | Format-Table
```

I was able to get the output for the first 3 cases, but the data seems to repeat several times for the last case. I dont understand why the  last case repeats.

Source file:

```
"SampleNumber","TypeIndicator","ResultName","Indicator","ResultEntry"
"111","10","S","","125.234"
"111","10","Sn","","0.034"
"111","10","Mo","","0.307"
"111","10","Cr ","u","0.022"
"111","10","Sb","u","-0.096"
"111","10","P","","1.593"
"111","10","Zn","","0.126"
"111","ND","S","o","113.920"
"111","ND","Sn","","0.019"
"111","ND","Mo","","0.278"
"111","ND","Cr ","","0.003"
"111","ND","Sb","","0.008"
"111","ND","P","","1.445"
"111","ND","Zn","","0.045"
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, I did not have to assign to a variable, I just had to pipe the object to Select-Object and Change the column name

```
$ND | Select-Object -Property @{Name='SampleNumber';Expression={$ND.SampleNumber}},   etc...
```